# React Alt Calling a store method synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alt

Developing a React/Alt application, I face a quite common scenario:
In the root component, in a button click handler, I need to check if a value in a specific store is valid before triggering an action. This value is not yet available in the state of the store since it has to be calculated.
So I have to call an action linked on the method of the store which going to calculate the value. The result will be stored in the state of the store and will be available in the listen-handler of the root component.
Unfortunately, in this case, I lose the initial context of the user action.
I'd like to synchronously calculate the value and retrieve it in the same context. Is there a way to do it? What are the best practices in such a scenario?
Thanks.

Comment: So I presume the actual value of that state isn't depending on the button itself? As in, the button isn't changing the value, a text input, for example is. What I do is I keep the button state disabled until the value is correct, or I make sure that when the button is pushed, the state is already calculated. This can be done simply by, using the example text input, pushing the changes of that input to the store and calculating it. That way you always have the correct state. Could you elaborate why the value isn't available in the state of the store?

Comment: The more accurate example is a form store that handles all the form values.

Comment: Ok, and how would an action on a Button be handling on a stale store?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake writing my comment : The more relevant example is a form store that handles all the values of a form. When the user clicks a button, whatever the button is, I need to check if the form is valid (iterate through the values and validate them). To keep the state up-to-date all the time, I should validate the form each time the user interacts with the inputs. This solution is pretty performance-greedy. I just need to validate the form once.

Comment: Ah understood. I normally validate the form on every update but obviously that can deliver performance downsides. What you can do is do the validation not in the store but in a separate module, and validate it on the press of the button. So you can use either your props, or store.getState() and feed this into the library. Would that work? I use this in one location. Separating this into a module makes it testable + reusable and it removes the logic from your react component.

Comment: You mean having the validation logic in a distinct module. The module could have a validate method to which I would pass the store state and in return I would get the validation status? If so, yes it's a good idea.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'd suggest. You can of course just put it in your React component but it's probably cleaner to split off.

Comment: I added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your validation logic up into a separate module. On the `onClick` handler you can then execute this validation logic, using either `store.getState()` or the props of your component. The validation logic will then be separate from your component, which makes it easy to test and re-use, plus it won't clutter your component, which should be more concerned with behavior of the interface.